# Assigning the reference of a stack allocated variable to a pointer

Tags: c++

Given the following function:

```
void test(queue<string>* out) {
   queue<string> abc = queue<string>();
   abc.push("abc");
   out = &abc;
}
```

Theoretically, the `abc` variable is allocated on the stack and at the end of the function it must automatically pop out of the stack. But I am assigning the reference of that variable to the `out` parameter which is a pointer. So when the context which calls this function pass a pointer to capture the output, what would happen? In other words, is this operation safe at all?

To make the question very clear, is the following function equivalent to the above:

```
void test(queue<string>* out) {
   out->push("abc");
}
```

Comment: nope - thats undefined behavior in your first example

Comment: `out = &abc;` means nothing to the caller. Furthermore, `out` in this example means nothing to the function; it is never used. `out` is a value parameter (whose value happens to be an address, but who cares). You may also want to work on vernacular, "But I am assigning the reference of that variable" is not correct; you're assigning the *address* of that variable to `out`, but the caller will never see it regardless. Whatever was passed to `test` from the caller for that argument will remain as-was.

Comment: @WhozCraig: the actual question is that at the end of the function, the `abc` must pop out of the stack, but I am keeping its address/reference in another place and I expect to use it, so what happens? is that a bad approach?

Comment: Both `out` and `abc` end their lifetimes at the end of your function.  Your function only modifies variables that are immediately destroyed.  Your function effectively does nothing.

Comment: What happens is you use 'freed' stack memory, that could be overwritten... Pass queue as reference and use `std::swap (out, abc)`

Comment: You're not keeping its address in another place.  `out` is local. It is a value argument. `out = ...` means nothing to the caller of `test`. If you were to pass that pointer argument by-reference (e.g. `queue<string>*& out`, *then* you have issues (all of them bad), but right now what you have is tantamount to an expensive no-op.

Comment: @WhozCraig: that is exactly what I meant `queue<string>*&` sorry will edit the question. But can you explain to me if my theory is correct in that case?

Comment: If that is really a reference-to-pointer argument, besides invalidating half the comments on this question and at least half of one answer below, it indeed introduces a dangling pointer, caller-side the dereference of which invokes UB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first function is safe, but not equivalent to the second.

You are just assigning a value to the pointer `out` which is a local variable. That local variable is not connected to the caller and the assignment is not observable by the caller. Your function has no side-effects. It is equivalent to

```
void test(queue<string>* out) {}
```

---

You have not stored a pointer of the `abc` object anywhere reachable from outside the function.

If you had done so, that pointer would be dangling after the function call returns, because the `abc` object will be destroyed at that point. Whether you hold a reference/pointer to it does not matter at all. Variables declared at block scope (without `static` or `thread_local` specifiers) have *automatic storage duration*, meaning that they will be destroyed at the end of the block in which they are declared, always.

Dereferencing the dangling pointer would then cause the program to have *undefined behavior*, meaning that you lose any guarantees on the program behavior.

For this reason it is a clear mistake to return a reference or pointer to a local variable, whether through the return value or out-parameters.

Answer (score 3):

> So when the context which calls this function pass a pointer to capture the output, what would happen?

Its unclear what you mean by "capture the output". The function has no output.

> In other words, is this operation safe at all?

The problem isn't so much with safety, rather the function doesn't do anything useful.

> But I am assigning the reference of that variable to the out parameter which is a pointer.

This is fine because the pointer parameter itself doesn't have a (significantly) longer lifetime.

> Is the following function equivalent to the above:

The functions aren't equivalent. The first function doesn't indirect through the pointer parameter and doesn't modify the queue that is pointed.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. I'd rather rewrite like this:

```cpp
using StringQueue = std::queue<std::string>;
void test( StringQueue& out) {
   out.push("abc");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. I'd rather rewrite like this:

```cpp
using StringQueue = std::queue<std::string>;
void test( StringQueue*& out ) {
   out = new StringQueue;
   out->push( "abc" );
}
```